# New EXIF tags are always "Unknown tag"

Tags: c#, image, metadata, exif

This is how I add some custom EXIF tags to a image:

```
PropertyItem propItem = file.PropertyItems[0];
propItem.Id = //ID
propItem.Type = 2;
propItem.Value = //Value
propItem.Len = //Length
file.SetPropertyItem(propItem);
```

Example can be found [here](http://www.thevalvepage.com/swmonkey/2013/12/23/exif-tags-in-c/)

But the tag does not have a name:

[image: All tags are unknown]

How can I add a name to a PropertyItem?

Comment: Well, no, tags do not have a name, only an ID.  When you make them "custom" then whatever software interprets the tags has no idea what they might mean and cannot match them to a documented EXIF tag.  0x7001 is not a standard EXIF tag, it is unknown.  So this is entirely normal.

Comment: @HansPassant So there is no way to give a name?